# $f(z)$, a function that is analytic in field $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let there be $f(z)$, a function that is analytic in field $D$. Prove that if $|f(z)|=\text{const}$ for every $z$ in $D$, then the function $f(z)$ is constant in $D$.
field $D$ is connected and opened disk *

There is a solution by our university's prof, but I think it's wrong,
solution: We define a new function $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{e^z - 1}$

We note that $g(z)$ is analytic for every $z$ except $z=2\pi ni$ for some integer $n$. We also pay attention that $g(z) \leq 1$ for every neighborhood around those singular points.
to be honet I didn't get it why $g(z) \leq 1$ , and if may someone help me in a direction I would be thankful

Comment: What do you mean by field $D$?

Comment: We call a field as a simple opened disk

Comment: So $D$ is **open and connected**. Isn't it?

Comment: I am sorry I said it's simple , it's opened and connected you are correct!

Comment: Will you accept any other solution (one that doesn't involve defining $g$)?

Comment: of course brother anything

Comment: Then here is a hint for you: Suppose that $f=u+iv$ and use Cauchy Riemann's equations.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Another approach: If we assume that $f$ is non constant, then the image of $D$ under $f$ must be an open set by open mapping thm. But $|f|\equiv \text{constant}$ means the image of $D$ is a connected subset of some circle centered around the origin, which is a contradiction. So, $f$ must be constant.